# What part of Windows Security does Control+Alt+Delete invoke?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, group-policy, hotkeys

This is with the computer logged in.

I'm wondering what process is activated to display the GUI that has lock, switch user, task manager, etc. / what the location of it is

And if it is more than just an executable, what is the process that takes place after pressing Control+Alt+Delete to get to that point?

I've read on Wikipedia that "pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete invokes Windows Security". When I was trying to research it online I was only getting results for Windows Defender.

Combing through the computer I found some files in "C:\Windows\WinSxS\" that had to do with Windows Security, but nothing really obvious. I also couldn't find anything in the Windows or System32 folder.

Comment: I suspect this Security Stack Exchange question [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34972/whats-the-rationale-behind-ctrl-alt-del-for-login) answers your question.  The key combination This combination is called a **Secure attention key**.  The environment entered is the **Secure Desktop** which is the same environment that is used for UAC prompts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is with the computer logged in.

Actually, it doesn't really matter. The mechanism by which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> works is not really related to whether or not you are logged in.

> I'm wondering what process is activated to display the GUI that has
>   lock, switch user, task manager, etc. / what the location of it is
>
> And if it is more than just an executable, what is the process that
>   takes place after pressing Control+Alt+Delete to get to that point?

As a commenter mentioned, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is a secure attention key - basically a secure key combination. Similar to the way UAC dialogs dim your desktop (by default), it is designed to ensure that rogue processes don't hijack sensitive actions.

The most popular application of this is **Windows Secure Logon**, which makes use of the key combination to login. I personally enable this on all of my PCs; partly because I think it's cool, and partly because it ensures that you're typing your password into Windows and not something else.

> I've read on Wikipedia that "pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete invokes Windows
>   Security". When I was trying to research it online I was only getting
>   results for Windows Defender.

That might have been Windows Secure Logon to which the post was referring, which makes use of this key combo.

> Combing through the computer I found some files in
>   "C:\Windows\WinSxS\" that had to do with Windows Security, but nothing
>   really obvious. I also couldn't find anything in the Windows or
>   System32 folder.

I can't speak to whether something in here is involved or not, but I would be doubtful that a file is involved here since it makes use of this secure key combination.

However, Windows is free to handle the key combination as it likes. When you're already logged in, the key combination is used to perform other security tasks. I believe you're referring to the menu of five or fewer options you see in Windows 7 and later; in previous versions of Windows, this key combination opens Task Manager or allows you to restart your computer.